# Вставка строки в QTableView при нажатии клавиши

Tags: qt

При нажатии на клавишу enter в QTableView вставляется новая строка. Как это отключить?

Пробовал переопределить eventFilter() но после этого все равно вставляется строка когда фокус не на таблице.

```
bool TableView::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) 
    {
        QKeyEvent* pKeyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        switch(pKeyEvent->key()) 
        {
            case Qt::Key_Enter:
            break;
            case Qt::Key_Return:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return QWidget::eventFilter(watched, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте добавить event->ignore() в случаях enter и return

Comment: Это дает возможность добавить строки...